# Database Schema, Default Value is NOW()

Tags: mysql, datetime, time, mysql-error-1067

I have database schema for users. It looks like...

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (

`id` int( 8 ) unsigned AUTO_INCREMENT,
`username` varchar( 255 ),
`password` varchar( 40 ),
`level` tinyint( 1 ) unsigned DEFAULT 1,
`time` datetime DEFAULT NOW(),
`email` varchar( 255 ),

PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

There are six fields: *id*, *username*, *password*, *level*, *time*, *email*, but I want to insert only three of them - when user is registration: *username*, *password* and *email*. Rest of them will have default values.

Problem is that MySQL throws error: **#1067 - Invalid default value for 'time'**. Any ideas, guys?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, and change the column to timestamp.

It does the same, but works (as long as you can live with timestamp) - it is a limitation.

Discussions:

1. http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=27645
2. http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?61,67640,67771#msg-67771

So your create becomes

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
`id` int( 8 ) unsigned AUTO_INCREMENT,
`username` varchar( 255 ),
`password` varchar( 40 ),
`level` tinyint( 1 ) unsigned DEFAULT 1,
`time` timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`email` varchar( 255 ),
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `TimeStamp` not `DateTime`

```
`time` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, MySQL does not support functions as default values. There's only one exception as far as I know: you can assign `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to a `TIMESTAMP` column. So you need to either change your column type (being aware that `TIMESTAMP` is not as powerful as `DATETIME`) or rely on a trigger to fill the value.

Answer (score 0):

we can't make the  "DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" when my attribute is "datetime" so we will change our attribute to "TIMESTAMP" like:

`time` *** datetime*** DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

```
should be...
```

`time` **TIMESTAMP** DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,